# Using POST method to SHOPIFY with Powershell

Tags: powershell, shopify, shopify-api

I am trying to use the following code

```
$uri="https://everything.myshopify.com/admin/api/202104/orders/ordernum/fulfillments.json"
$order = @{
    fulfillments= {
        id= 'id',
        fulfillment_status="fulfilled"
    }    
}
$apikey = "key"
$password = "password"
$headers = @{"Authorization" = "Basic "+[System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($apikey+":"+$password))}
$body = (ConvertTo-Json $order)

$body
$file = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Put -Body $body -ContentType 'application/json' -Headers $headers -UseBasicParsing
```

To change the fulfillment status of an order.

It is erroring however erroring with the message

Invoke-RestMethod: C:\Powershell Scripts\test.ps1:9:9 Line | 9 | $file
= Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post -Body $body -Content … | ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ | Response status code does not indicate success: 406 (Not Acceptable).

$Body =

```
    {
  "fulfillments": {
    "Attributes": [],
    "File": "C:\\Powershell Scripts\\test.ps1",
    "IsFilter": false,
    "IsConfiguration": false,
    "Module": null,
    "StartPosition": {
      "Content": "{\r\n        id= 'id',\r\n        fulfillment_status=\"fulfilled\"\r\n    }",
      "Type": 19,
      "Start": 140,
      "Length": 78,
      "StartLine": 3,
      "StartColumn": 19,
      "EndLine": 6,
      "EndColumn": 6
    },
    "DebuggerHidden": false,
    "Id": "6d564632-241c-4644-8ffd-8cb9c1a76daa",
    "Ast": {
      "Attributes": "",
      "UsingStatements": "",
      "ParamBlock": null,
      "BeginBlock": null,
      "ProcessBlock": null,
      "EndBlock": "id= 'id',\r\n        fulfillment_status=\"fulfilled\"",
      "DynamicParamBlock": null,
      "ScriptRequirements": null,
      "Extent": "{\r\n        id= 'id',\r\n        fulfillment_status=\"fulfilled\"\r\n    }",
      "Parent": "{\r\n        id= 'id',\r\n        fulfillment_status=\"fulfilled\"\r\n    }"
    }
  }
}
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: According to the API docs, you need to use PUT (not POST) to update an order - see "What you can do with Order" here - https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/orders/order

Comment: Thanks mclayton - I have changed it to put and am now receiving the error PS C:\Users\\OneDrive\Desktop> c:\Powershell Scripts\test.ps1
Invoke-RestMethod: C:\Powershell Scripts\test.ps1:9:9
Line |
   9 |  $file = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Put -Body $body -ContentT …
     |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | {"errors":{"order":"Required parameter missing or invalid"}}

Comment: Try logging your ```$body``` to the console (```write-host $body```) and comparing it to an example in the documentation - e.g. https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/orders/order#update-2021-04. Does it look the same, or are there any obvious differences?

Comment: I tried following the advice with ... $uri = "https://ahome-everything.myshopify.com/admin/api/2021-04/orders/*orderid*.json"
$order = @{
    fulfillment= {
        location_id= null,
        fulfillment_status="fulfilled"}    
}
$apikey = "apikey"
$password = "password"
$headers = @{"Authorization" = "Basic "+[System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($apikey+":"+$password))}
$body = (ConvertTo-Json $order)

$file = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Put -Body $body -ContentType 'application/json' -Headers $headers -UseBasicParsing  -still failing

Comment: Have you tried logging your ```$body``` to the console? What does it look like? Can you add it to your question? (Not as a comment)

Comment: Attached $body to question

Comment: That looks vastly different to, for example, the json required to update a phone number (from the documentation link I posted previously: ```{"order": {"id": 450789469, "phone": "+15145556677" } }```

Maybe try using a hard-coded body string to get *something* working with the API, and then work out how to generate json dynamically afterwards. Try, for example ```$body = "{ `"order`": { `"id`": <your_order_number>, `"phone`": `"<something_here>`" } }"``` and see if that updates the phone number per the example.

Comment: Thanks.. will give that a try